# Convert Mp3 to Wav with custom sampling rate

Tags: python, audio, ffmpeg, subprocess

I am trying to convert my Mp3 files to Wav.

when using pydub it works but I get a sampling rate of 8000Hz as default but I need it to be 16000.

I tried using SOX and subprocess but It does not work and gives me an error.

My Code is as Follows:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['ffmpeg', '-i', '/file/mp3/file.mp3',
                '-r', '16k', '/file/wav/file.wav'])
```

It return me a file with Sampling rate of 8000.

Comment: why not try https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python
it's a wrapper and may give you more detailed errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem comes from the option you're using. You shouldn't be using `-r` but `-ar`. As stated in [FFmpeg's documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#toc-Audio-Options) it the option to control the sample right of an audio.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jao for your answer.